# $f^{2}$ convex implies $f$ convex too?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is it true that if $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a positive smooth map such that $f^{2}$ is convex function, then $f$ is convex??

Answer (score 5):

$$ f(x) = \left( 1 + x^2 \right)^{1/4}  $$
The **squared** function is the blue curve and is one branch of the hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = -1.$

The original function is the red curve, for large $x$ the function can hardly be distinguished from $\sqrt x,$ second derivative negative.
[image]

[image]

[image]
I get the second derivative  (constant $p$ ) of
$$ (1 + x^2)^p  $$ as
$$ 2p \left(1 + x^2 \right)^{p-2} \left( 1 + (2p-1) x^2 \right) $$
When $p = \frac{1}{2}$ this is always positive. For $p = \frac{1}{4}$ this is negative when $x > \sqrt 2$